# js function ignores Decimal Numbers

Tags: javascript, php

So i made a function that calculate the price by multiplication how many meters i put the problem is when ever i put decimal numbers it ignores it

heres my script

```
<script>
function getFillingPrice() {
    cake_prices = document.getElementById('price').value;
    filling_prices = document.getElementById('test2').value;
    var t=parseInt(filling_prices);
    var x=parseInt(cake_prices);
    return t*x;
}


function calculateTotal() {
    var total = getFillingPrice();
    var totalEl = document.getElementById('totalPrice');

    document.getElementById('test3').value =total + " دينار ";
    totalEl.style.display = 'block';
}
  </script>
```

Comment: `parseInt` does what it says, parses an INT ... you want parseFloat instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting the values to integers when you get them from the DOM.

Change this...

```
var t=parseInt(filling_prices);
var x=parseInt(cake_prices);
```

to this...

```
var t=parseFloat(filling_prices);
var x=parseFloat(cake_prices);
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside the parsing problem, you could use

- an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) and
- a default value for non parsable value, like letters or an empty string ([falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values) with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()).

---

```
cake_price = +document.getElementById('price').value || 0
//           ^ unary plus for converting to numbner
//                                                   ^^^ default value for falsy values
```

Together

```
function getFillingPrice() {
    var cake_price = +document.getElementById('price').value || 0,
        filling_price = +document.getElementById('test2').value || 0;

    return cake_price * filling_price;
}
```

Comment: Will this fix the Not a number problem if the user input is a space or a letter?

Comment: it returns zero in this case. you may try it.

Comment: @Mynameisjeff `NaN` is a falsy value.